# How to look up a resource in Websphere 6.1

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-6.1

I have a web project and a source project.

In the web project I have a folder called `xsd` which I would like to access in my java files from the source project.

From a servlet or jsp I can access the xsd using

`getServletContext().getRealPath("/xsd")`

However, from the source project where I have no servletcontext, I don't know who to get hold of the `xsd` folder in the web project. I cannot use absolute path as this is unknown when the project is deployed to our production servers.

When I use `File` in java I get

`new File(".")` prints `C:\SDP75\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\` which does not contain my xsd folder and web project

How can I easily do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not put the xsd on the classpath and then do

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xsd/A.xsd");
```

It wouldn't give you a `File` but would that be sufficient?

EDIT: Removed leading `/` as that's only applicable to `Class.getResource()` not `Classloader.getResource()`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I needed. The strange this is that this is what I tried first. But I tried to see where I was first, and it didnt occur to me to just try the path. Anyways thanks alot!

Comment: This looks wrong.  The resource name passed to Class.getResource/AsStream should have a leading "/", but the one passed to ClassLoader.getResource/AsStream should not.